# SQL query to return a grouped result as a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

If I have a jobs table like:

```
|id|created_at  |status    |
----------------------------
|1 |01-01-2015  |error     |
|2 |01-01-2015  |complete  |
|3 |01-01-2015  |error     |
|4 |01-02-2015  |complete  |
|5 |01-02-2015  |complete  |
|6 |01-03-2015  |error     |
|7 |01-03-2015  |on hold   |
|8 |01-03-2015  |complete  |
```

I want a query that will group them by date and count the occurrence of each status and the total status for that date.

```
SELECT created_at status, count(status), created_at 
FROM jobs 
GROUP BY created_at, status;
```

Which gives me

```
|created_at  |status    |count|
-------------------------------
|01-01-2015  |error     |2
|01-01-2015  |complete  |1
|01-02-2015  |complete  |2
|01-03-2015  |error     |1
|01-03-2015  |on hold   |1
|01-03-2015  |complete  |1
```

I would like to now condense this down to a single row per `created_at` unique date with some sort of multi column layout for each `status`. One constraint is that `status` is any one of 5 possible words but each date might not have one of every status. Also I would like a total of all statuses for each day. So desired results would look like:

```
|date        |total |errors|completed|on_hold|
----------------------------------------------
|01-01-2015  |3     |2     |1        |null   
|01-02-2015  |2     |null  |2        |null
|01-03-2015  |3     |1     |1        |1
```

the columns could be built dynamically from something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT status FROM jobs;
```

with a null result for any day that doesn't contain any of that type of status. I am no SQL expert but am trying to do this in a DB view so that I don't have to bog down doing multiple queries in Rails.

I am using Postresql but would like to try to keep it straight SQL. I have tried to understand aggregate function enough to use some other tools but not succeeding.

Comment: As mentioned above, Postgres. But if there is a way to do it to be agnostic, that would be preferable.

Comment: Is the number of status values known (and fixed)?

Comment: Yes, status is one of 8 possible words.

Comment: Then Giorgos' answer should do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work in any RDBMS:

```
SELECT created_at, count(status) AS total,
       sum(case when status = 'error' then 1 end) as errors,
       sum(case when status = 'complete' then 1 end) as completed,
       sum(case when status = 'on hold' then 1 end) as on_hold
FROM jobs 
GROUP BY created_at;
```

The query uses *conditional aggregation* so as to *pivot* grouped data. It assumes that `status` values are known before-hand. If you have additional cases of `status` values, just add the corresponding `sum(case ...` expression.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c0350/2)

Comment: Perfect. I didn't think of using the `case` statement. Very simple. I will accept the answer in about 3 minutes when the system lets me. (I didn't know there was a "cooling off" period for accepting answers. LOL!)

Comment: @Beartech: with Postgres 9.4 you can also use the filter clause which does the same thing but makes it a bit more readable: `count(*) filter (where status = 'error') as errors`

Answer (score 2):

An **actual crosstab query** would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$SELECT created_at, status, count(*) AS ct
     FROM   jobs 
     GROUP  BY 1, 2
     ORDER  BY 1, 2$$

  ,$$SELECT unnest('{error,complete,"on hold"}'::text[])$$)
AS ct (date date, errors int, completed int, on_hold int);
```

Should perform very well.

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

The above does not yet include the total per date.
Postgres **9.5** introduces the [ROLLUP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) clause, which is perfect for the case:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
 $$SELECT created_at, COALESCE(status, 'total'), ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT created_at, status, count(*) AS ct
      FROM   jobs 
      GROUP  BY created_at, ROLLUP(status)
      ) sub
   ORDER  BY 1, 2$$

  ,$$SELECT unnest('{total,error,complete,"on hold"}'::text[])$$)
AS ct (date date, total int, errors int, completed int, on_hold int);
```

Up to Postgres **9.4**, use this query instead:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT created_at, status, count(*) AS ct
    FROM   jobs 
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    )
TABLE  cte
UNION  ALL
SELECT created_at, 'total', sum(ct)
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1
```

Related:

- [Grouping() equivalent in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94822/3684)

---

If you want to stick to a **simple query**, this is a bit shorter:

```
SELECT created_at
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(status = 'error' OR NULL)    AS errors
     , count(status = 'complete' OR NULL) AS completed
     , count(status = 'on hold' OR NULL)  AS on_hold
FROM   jobs 
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`count(status)` for the total per date is error-prone, because it would not count rows with NULL values in `status`. Use `count(*)` instead, which is also shorter and a bit faster.

Here is a list of techniques:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

In Postgres **9.4+** use the new aggregate `FILTER` clause, [like @a_horse mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244059/sql-query-to-return-a-grouped-result-as-a-single-row#comment56230117_34244103):

```
SELECT created_at
     , count(*) AS total
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'error')    AS errors
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'complete') AS completed
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'on hold')  AS on_hold
FROM   jobs 
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Details:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)